# Can someone explain how .extend() works in depth for this example?

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to understand a bit more in-depth how Python lists work. And am confused about what it can and cannot receive as a parameter.

```py
def foo(i: int, lst: list): -> list
    [i].extend(lst) #nothing happens
    ([i]).extend(lst) #nothing happens
    (list((i,i)).extend(lst) #nothing happens
    var_list = [2,2]    
    new_lst_3 = var_list.extend(lst) # this works
```

My theory is that some of these list methods only work on arguments if the variable points to a type list, because they don't return a value. Since the pointer would be to a list, the list method can then properly modify the value that the pointer points to.

I may be totally off base, but any clarification on this would be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `new_lst_3 = var_list.extend(lst)` doesn't really work, it sets `new_lst_3` as `None`. I can't work out what you're trying to do

Comment: In all the cases where '#nothing happens'  you create an anonymous list `[i]` which is not assigned to any var.

Comment: its very important to understand, **python doesn't have pointers**. In any case, the answer here is simple, `.extend` is a method that works in-place on list objects, and will return `None` (which is generally true for mutator methods of Python built-in objects). In your first three examples, you create a list and use `.extend` on it, but never once keep a reference to the list you created (or even capture the return value), so i'm not sure what you are **expecting**. in the case that "works", `new_lst_3` is not a list, but `None`, the list being referenced by `var_list` is mutated.

Comment: `[i].extend(lst) #nothing happens` you're extending `[i]` but it's essentially discarded because you haven't assigned `[i]` to a variable name.

Comment: `-> list` goes before the `:`. Real code is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `extend()` method you're working with *mutates* the list that it is called on. Something is happening in each of the lines you have commented; the catch is that in the first three lines, you are throwing away the results.

```py
[i].extend(lst)  # Creates a temporary list [i], adds the elements of lst, and 
                 # then... the list disappears because it's not assigned to a variable
([i]).extend(lst)  # Ditto
(list((i,i)).extend(lst)  # Same again

var_list = [2,2]    
new_lst_3 = var_list.extend(lst) # Adds the elements of lst to var_list, and you can see the changes
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Clearly explained my confusion!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using extend. So the idea is that you have a list and you want to add (extend) another list to the original list. The call to `extend` return None

```
lst = [1,2]
lst.extend([3,4])
print(lst)
```

output

```
[1,2,3,4]
```